# Error Handling in Login Form

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

Made Login form with email and password text fields and connecting it with server and son response but when i click login button it crashes and shows me error. Here is my code:

```
 -(IBAction)Login:(id)sender{
    if ([self.emailID.text isEqualToString:@""]){
        UIAlertController *alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter Email" message:@"Enter Your Email Address" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *actionOk=[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alert addAction:actionOk];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }else if ([self.password.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertController *alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter Password" message:@"Enter Your Password" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *actionOk=[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alert addAction:actionOk];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Login Successfully");

    }

        NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
        NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
        //Valid email address

        if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:_emailID.text] == YES)
        {
            // NSLog(@"Correct Email");
        }
        else
        { UIAlertController *alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Invalid Email" message:@"Email Formatt is Incorrect" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction *actionOk=[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
            [alert addAction:actionOk];
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:NULL];
        }
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@ & password=%@",_emailID.text,_password.text];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myURL"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
    }] resume];

    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143026/discussion-on-question-by-omer-error-handling-in-login-form).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is type casting issue so you need to replace your line with

```
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
```

**AND**

You have to add just the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES in NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your info.plist file

Comment: why down vote ?

Comment: seriously i don't know. @KKRocks